# Two controls to Manipulate all elements of a list

Tags: manipulate, dynamic

Say, I have a list `list` and I don't want to assign different names to all its elements.

What I want to do it to be able to interactively manipulate any of the elements of `list`. And if my selection of an element changes, then the slider of its value has to reset to its current value.

This is what I have tried (in fact, all this happens inside a massive `DynamicModule` inside a `Manipulate`):

```
list=Table[0,{i,1,100}];
Manipulate[
Refresh[x=list[[elementChoice]], TrackedSymbols:>{elementChoice}];
Refresh[list[[elementChoice]]=x, TrackedSymbols:>{x}];
,
{{elementChoice,1,"Element's number"},1,Length[list],1},{{x,0,"element's value"},0,1}]
```

but it just resets `x` to zero if I try to change it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like that?

```
list = Range[0, 9];
DynamicModule[{nr, val},
 Column[{
   Dynamic@list,
   Dynamic@list[[ nr]],
   Slider[Dynamic@nr, {1, 10, 1}],
   Slider[Dynamic[list[[ nr]]], {0, 10, 1}]
   }]
 ]
```

`Manipulate` version:

```
list = Range[0, 9];
Manipulate[
 Column[{list, list[[nr]]}],
 Column[{
   Control[{{nr, 1}, 1, 10, 1}],
   Slider[Dynamic[list[[nr]]], {0, 10, 1}]
   }]]
```

Comment: This is OK on its own, but is it possible to incorporate something like this into the standard Manipulate environment? For example, if `nr` is already one of the controls in Manipulate and is used for other evaluations. Then can I put the `val` slider alongside other controls in Manipulate?

Comment: Wow, I didn't even expect it to be this simple. The "dynamic inside dynamic" stuff always gives me a hard time :)

Comment: @level1807 only the body of `Manipulate` is wrapped with `Dynamic`. Try to put `nr` between `Control` and `Slider`, it won't update.

Comment: Interesting, thank you.

Comment: can I ask you one more question? In the following (incorrect) code `Manipulate[DynamicModule[{x}, x = y; Refresh[x = x^p, TrackedSymbols :> {p}]; x], Grid[{{Slider[Dynamic@y, {0, 5}, Appearance -> "Labeled"]}}], {p, 0, 5, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]` I want the piece under `Refresh` only be evaluated when `p` is changed. Can I do this without removing the structure of `DynamicModule` inside `Manipulate`?

Comment: @level1807 it does not work because whole body of `Manipulate` is effectively in `Dynamic` so the shortest way is to suppress it with `Refresh[DynamicModule[ ...], None]`. It works as you need I think. But at the end I'm encouraging you to use only `DynamicModule` with no `Manipulate` for bigger projects. `Manipualte` can be tricky there.

Comment: wow, all this really looks like magic to me. And thanks for the advice, I'll try to get rid of Manipulate. Do you happen to know any nice learning resources for the "advanced dynamic functionality" besides the official documentation?

Comment: @level1807 The problem is I don't! It's a pitty, I've lost so much time and still I don't consider myself an expert :) Most of things I've learned are from here so SE is a good resource. It is also educational to parse CDF codes that are around.

Comment: Yeah, it's a pity. Obviously, I'm finding SE extremely helpful as well. Wow, you're from Krakow? I'll be going to Beskidy in two weeks :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15522/discussion-between-kuba-and-level1807).